# move uploaded document from a library to another library in different site collection

Tags: 2013, office-365, 2016, nintex

Is it possible to move the uploaded document from a library to another library in different site collection using SharePoint designer workflow or Nintex workflow?

I tried Nintex workflow, but it only provides option to move document from one library to another library within same site collection. But I want to move it across site collection.

Is it possible using SharePoint designer or Nintex?

Answer (score 1):

I think, We use the Remote event receivers for this. 
 1) Create a  remote event receiver for the document library 
2)  Make sure that **allow the app to make app-only calls to sharepoint** is checked and the app has Tenant level control to write files
[image] 
 3). use the below code in the remove event receiver to copy the document

```
 string filePath = "/sites/dev/Copy/TypeScript_Succinctly.pdf";
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
        using (var sourceContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sourceFile = sourceContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
            //file stream will be used to upload in destination library
            var fileStream = sourceFile.OpenBinaryStream();
            sourceContext.Load(sourceFile, k => k.ServerRelativeUrl, k => k.Name);
            sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //generate destination context
            string destinationSiteUrl = "https://tarun.sharepoint.com/sites/dev1";
            Uri destinationSiteUri = new Uri(destinationSiteUrl);
            //target realm of the tenant (This is constant per tenant)
            string targetRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(destinationSiteUri);
            //generate access token for destination site
            string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, destinationSiteUri.Authority, targetRealm).AccessToken;
            //get destination site context using access token
            using (var destinationContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(destinationSiteUrl, accessToken))
            {
                //load server relative url of destination library
                var destinationLibrary = destinationContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Paste");
                FileCreationInformation fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                fileCreationInfo.ContentStream = fileStream.Value;
                fileCreationInfo.Url = sourceFile.Name;
                fileCreationInfo.Overwrite = false;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File destinationFile = destinationLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
                destinationContext.Load(destinationFile, k => k.ServerRelativeUrl);
                destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                lbl_Success.Text = "Copied Sucessfully";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using open to explorer option which works in IE. Open both library location in IE, click open to explorer under libraries above , once it opens copy and just paste it in the desired library.

Comment: thanks, I want this to happen whenever document is uploaded to a library